# Creating a service to determine the string format based on user's session

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have a need to format a bank account number based on the user's country. So rather than passing the location for each time I need the value, e.g:

```
Account.FormatBankAccountNumber("AU", bsb, accountNumber)
```

I was thinking of creating a service which would read the location from the user's session (which we have customised to store the location).

So far this is what I have:

```
public class AccountUtilityService : Service
{
    public string FormatBankAccountNumber(string bsb, string accountNumber, bool obfuscate = false)
    {
        var session = base.SessionAs<CustomAuthSession>();

        if (obfuscate) {
            accountNumber = accountNumber.ObfuscationSensitiveInformation();
        }
        if (session.Region == RegionCodes.AU) {
            return string.Format("({0}) - {1}", bsb, accountNumber);
        }
        return accountNumber;
    }
}
```

Then I would just have to auto wire it like so:

```
container.RegisterAutoWired<AccountDetailUtilityService>().ReusedWithin(Funq.ReuseScope.None);
```

So now all the services which require this can just have the AccountUtilityService injected and it will automatically return the format according to the user's session without having to specify what the user's location is.

This works, but just wanted to see if others had thoughts for a better way to do this?

Comment: Just wondering, doesn't BSB and Account Number only make sense in Australia? that wouldn't make the FormatBankAccountNumber very generic.

Comment: You're right, I guess I was thinking this could be one of many of these kinds of logic. This example is probably not a very good one.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say explicitly specifying the format when converting to string is actually more clear; in fact .NET Framework does it everywhere.

Also following .NET Framework's convention, I'd turn BankAccount to a class (and maybe include the account's country in there), and leave the formatting responsibility to itself by overriding the `ToString` method, while providing a default formatting if one is not specified.

Comment: Yea this is kinda the direction I was heading towards, but was wondering if there was a better way. Cheers!